# Entity Tokens + Date Field + Custom Format... unable to use spaces

Tags: 7, datetime, tokens

I have a content type (Question of the Week)... with a Date field (Used for "Publish Date". Questions won't be published until that date).

I am trying to custom format the Title for it without changing the default (Long, Medium, Short) date formats.

For "Pattern for the title"...
If I [node:field-jcqotw-date:custom:l] it shows the day (ex: Sunday).
If I [node:field-jcqotw-date:custom:lF] it shows the dayMonth, no space (ex: SundayJune).
If I [node:field-jcqotw-date:custom:l F] it shows "[node:field-jcqotw-date:custom:l F]" (ex: SundayJune).
If I [node:field-jcqotw-date:custom:l F] it shows "Sunday June" (ex: SundayJune).

I've tried "l F", 'l F', l\ F,   (non breaking space),   (Space), etc... Nothing I do seems to let "Custom" use a space.

Edit: After some research... it seems to be an Entity Tokens + CCK Date Field issue... I'll have to put an issue up in those places.

Why can't I use a space in the "Custom format"?

Also... I've created a "Date Type" simply called "myDate" => 'l F j, Y' ('Sunday June 5, 2011'). Is there a way to get Token to show that format? Long, medium, raw, short... "myDate"...

Edit: Updated Title and Question to be more correct. The problem has something to do with Entity API, Context, Date Field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this commit](http://drupalcode.org/project/date.git/commit/05060c8) to Date module, token integration was removed, because [field tokens aren't working yet](http://drupal.org/node/691078).

The error you got it reproducible with an older copy of Date module, but doesn't seem to be related at all to Automatic Nodetitles, just Date/Token.

I would wait until the above Token issue and the Date issue [Re-Add Field Token Support](http://drupal.org/node/1103032) are committed.

Comment: I think it has to do with Entity API/Entity Tokens + Date module. From a little research it seems as if the CCK fields are available after enabling the "Entity Tokens" addon. I'll have to put an issue up there, although I've just used .'s instead of spaces as a stop-gap.

Comment: The Entity API contrib module may or may not provide it's own tokens, but those aren't the ones that will end up being fully supported by the Token module. Also, CCK does not exist in D7, the part of it that is in core is the Field API.

Comment: CCK, as a module, does exist in 7 (provides "extra" stuff...). The tokens I'm using, afaik, are from a combination of Entity API, Entity Tokens, Tokens, Date API (More or less). Must just be something buggish in the "custom" part that isn't allowing me to use spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a core bug that spaces cannot be used in 'dynamic' tokens. You may want to try the patches available in http://drupal.org/node/1035292.

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert the token multiple times, each time inserting only one part of your date format.  The spaces between are then correctly interpreted.

```
<div class="posted-on">%node:created:custom:M %node:created:custom:j, %node:created:custom:Y</div>
```